# gke cant disable Transparent Huge Pages... permission denied

Tags: redis, permission-denied, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to run a redis image in gke. It works except I get the dreaded "Transparent Huge Pages" warning:

```
WARNING you have Transparent Huge Pages (THP) support enabled in your kernel. This will create latency and memory usage issues with Redis. To fix this issue run the command 'echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled' as root, and add it to your /etc/rc.local in order to retain the setting after a reboot. Redis must be restarted after THP is disabled.
```

Redis is currently too slow to be useful... So I tied turning off THP:

```
sheena@gke-projectwaxd-cluster-default-pool-23593a74-wxrv ~ $ cat  /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
always [madvise] never
sheena@gke-projectwaxd-cluster-default-pool-23593a74-wxrv ~ $ echo never >  /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled 
-bash: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled: Permission denied
sheena@gke-projectwaxd-cluster-default-pool-23593a74-wxrv ~ $ sudo echo never >  /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled 
-bash: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled: Permission denied
```

These permission errors are disconcerting. Redis wants THP off so it can work properly.

I did a little digging and found that google uses a special os image that makes /sys/ a read-only path. There's an alternative image that's based on Debian 7. It got me all excited but in the end I have exactly the same problem.

So how do I stop redis from being effected by THP on Google container engine?

It's not like I'm doing something unique here. Running databases in containers is pretty normal. And it's pretty normal for a database to malfunction when THP is enabled. So... what am I missing here?

Answer (score 7):

Your command is slightly incorrect: `echo` runs as root but the redirection itself (`>`) runs as user so it can't write `/sys/`.

The following command works fine **both** on container-vm (debian based) and gci (chromeos based):

```
sudo sh -c 'echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled'
```

### Persisting this setting on container-vm

Add this kernel command line parameter into `/etc/default/grub` (don't forget to run `sudo update-grub` and `sudo reboot` afterwards):

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="... transparent_hugepage=never"
```

### Persisting this setting on gci

First, using the cloud console copy the instance template that is in use by the node pool.

Second, under metadata change the value for userdata:

```
#cloud-config

write_files:
  - path: /etc/systemd/system/hugepage.service
    permissions: 0644
    owner: root
    content: |
      [Unit]
      Description=Disable THP

      [Service]
      Type=oneshot
      ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled"

      [Install]
      WantedBy=kubernetes.target
...
runcmd:
 - ...
 - systemctl enable hugepage.service
 - systemctl start kubernetes.target
```

Third, change the instance template to the newly created one:

```
gcloud compute instance-groups managed set-instance-template \
  gke-YOUCLUSTER-YOURPOOL-grp \
  --template=YOURNEWTEMPLATENAME \
  --zone=...
```

Forth, recreate the instace(s):

```
gcloud compute instance-groups managed recreate-instances \
   gke-YOUCLUSTER-YOURPOOL-grp \
   --zone=... \
   --instances=...
```

The instances will **loose all data** and come up with THP disabled. All new instances will have THP disabled as well (in this node pool).

Comment: Amazing. Thanks for this! Followed these steps (Persisting this setting on gci) and it works perfectly

Comment: yes, amazing, that works well. Thank you so much @janos lenart. The command line is the way to go. 

Now, I tried to the last step (recreate instances) on the web console, by replace in the instance group after the template was updated, but it made the GKE cluster hang, and some of the kube could not be restarted. But the command line above worked like a charm.

Comment: On a side now, I can't believe GKE does not allow to create a cluster with an instance template. It seems to have to create the cluster first, set instance template to each node pool second, and then, recreate the instances. I must be missing something.

Comment: Thanks :-) It's been a year since I wrote this answer but I'm yet to find a better solution. I'm happy that it's useful.