# How to pass `sysctl` flags to docker from k8s?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Scanario: I have a container image that needs to run with `net.core.somaxconn` > default_value. I am using Kubernetes to deploy and run in GCE.

The nodes (vms) in my cluster are configured with correct `net.core.somaxconn` value. Now the challenge is to start the docker container with flag `--sysctl=net.core.somaxconn=4096` from kubernetes. I cannot seem to find the proper documentation to achieve this.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43032406/gke-cant-disable-transparent-huge-pages-permission-denied/43081893#43081893

Comment: @JanosLenart the vm is configured correctly but how do I pass this flag to the container from kubernetes.

Comment: Have you got multiple VMs with multiple sysctl configurations? You can put a label on the nodes that use a VM with the needed configuration and use nodeSelector in the Pod spec to force scheduling to those nodes. Or maybe I have misunderstood your question.

Comment: Actually your answer focuses on setting up the vms in the cluster. I am looking for a way to start my docker container using `--sysctl=net.core.somaxconn=4096` from kubernetes.

Comment: @JanosLenart I have updated my question and tags. The previous one was too vague and misleading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1**: use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43032406/gke-cant-disable-transparent-huge-pages-permission-denied/43081893#43081893) as a template to see how to configure the whole node to that sysctl value; you can use something like `echo 4096 >/proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn`. Thereafter you can put a label on the nodes that use a VM with the needed sysctl configuration and use nodeSelector in the Pod spec to force scheduling to those nodes. (This only works with *non* namespaced settings; sys.net.core.somaxconn appears to be namespaced. I would like to leave this solution here as it might help others.)

**Solution 2**: again, starting from [same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43032406/gke-cant-disable-transparent-huge-pages-permission-denied/43081893#43081893) you can add `--experimental-allowed-unsafe-sysctls=net.core.somaxconn` to the `kubelet` command line (This only works with *namespaced* settings; sys.net.core.somaxconn is namespaced). Then you can simply do something like ([source](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/sysctl-cluster/#enabling-unsafe-sysctls)):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: sysctl-example
  annotations:
    security.alpha.kubernetes.io/sysctls: net.core.somaxconn=4096
```

I hope this helps..

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation. Any idea how I can add `--experimental-allowed-unsafe..` to kubelet using GCE's instance_templates. can't seem to find appropriate config var to do that?

Comment: Try: https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/using-systemd-drop-in-units.html (there is a cloud-config example too)

Comment: Hint: `Environment="KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS=..."`

Comment: Thanks that solved my problem, but the irony is `GCE core-os` does not have the latest docker version to allow, this. Will figure this out.

Comment: Last resort: make container privileged and execute the sysctl command/echo from it